# In React-Native, when use appcenter with i18n, the duplicate react-native error

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-app-center

In React-Native, I am using appcenter and react-native-i18n.
Initially, I installed appcenter and then react-native-i18n.

When I try to upgrade appcenter, in Pods directory, the react is installed with new node_modules folder.
After that, the duplicate module error is occurred.
The npm start doesn't work anymore.

```
jest-haste-map: @providesModule naming collision:
  Duplicate module name: VibrationIOS
```

Please help me.

Comment: The react-native-i18n is deprecated, but the project is large, so I cannot migrate into other library.

Comment: Try Adding jest --clearCache before starting React Native i.e,. `"scripts": {
"start": "yarn jest --clearCache && react-native-scripts start",`

Comment: I tried to run 'npm start -- --reset-cache'. It doesn't work too.

Comment: Hi, if this problem is related to using the App Center SDK, you will get support by creating an issue at https://github.com/Microsoft/AppCenter-SDK-React-Native/issues.